# What modules are distributed with Perl?

Tags: perl, module

How do I know what modules are distributed with Perl?

My first guess is that the core modules listed [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-modules-A.html) are always included, though I cannot find this stated explicitly. However, I have used modules outside this set (e.g. LWP) without having to install them on Mac OS X and Linux.

So to refine my question a little:

- What modules are distributed with all Perl installations?

And: How do I find out what modules have been distributed with:

- Linux (particularly Debian/Ubuntu)?
- Mac OS X?
- Solaris?

In each case I am using the version of Perl that comes standard with the most recent version of the operating system.

TIA.

**Update:** The reason for the question is that I am developing on Mac OS X and Linux for deployment to different Linux and Solaris, and I don't have root on some of these systems, and in the case of Mac OS X I don't even have a compiler AFAIK. So what I want to know what modules I have available in all four deployments without further installs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a quick way to see the modules and versions that you have installed, use the cpan tool to create an autobundle:

```
 cpan -a
```

ExtUtils::Installed can help you if you need something more sophisticated.

There used to be the idea of a "standard library", but it doesn't really  exist in reality. [Module::CoreList](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Module-CoreList) tells you what is in the "standard library", but many vendors install additional modules and some even remove or update modules. Additionally, distributions such as [Strawberry Perl](http://www.strawberryperl.com) and [ActivePerl](http://www.activestate.com) come with many bonus modules.

Also, you don't need root to install modules. You only need root to install modules where root can install modules. [perlfaq8](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq8.html) gives you all the details for installing modules wherever you like. I recommend that you install all modules outside of the distributed @INC directories so you keep your distributed Perl clean.

Good luck,

Comment: I did not use cpan -a (see my own answer being modded down below for the hack I did actually use) I would have if you had replied a month ago, so I'm flagging this as the right answer! Thanks. I was sure there had to be a way, and this will be useful information for the future.

Answer (score 15):

If you install [Module::CoreList](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Module::CoreList), the command line program `corelist` can tell you everything about modules and their versions in different versions of perl. The page you linked to gives an overview for the latest version of perl.

Do note that distributions often provide much more by default than this list, but this list can be assumed to be present everywhere (unless it is explicitly a OS dependent module such as Win32).

Comment: Although this should be the right answer, in practice vendors do wacky things when they build Perl. We'll need modules like Module::CoreList::Debian and so on :)

Answer (score 9):

The correct straight forward answers have already been given, but I think you've asked the wrong question.  You're probably trying to develop using only core modules.  Why?  You're probably doing this because you don't want to deal with dependencies.  Why?  Because they can be a pain in the ass.  But developing Perl without [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org) is missing half the power.  You're crippling yourself.  It's worth it.

**Update**:
Now that I know more about what you're trying to do, I can answer the right question.  First is "how do I install a module when I don't have root?"  The simple answer is this:

```
perl Makefile.PL PREFIX=/some/path LIB=/some/path/lib
...and all the rest as normal...
```

for MakeMaker based modules (LIB is used to control the otherwise inexact nature of PREFIX.  INSTALL_BASE is preferred, but it is not backwards compatible).

and this for Module::Build

```
perl Build.PL --install_base=/some/path
```

and then modules will wind up in /some/path/lib and you can set the `PERL5LIB` environment variable or `use lib qw(/some/path/lib)` in your code.

This means you can stick dependent modules straight into your software distribution and ship them.  Works fine for pure-Perl modules.  For stuff that requires a compiler, look at [PAR](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?pp) as others have suggested to be able to ship compiled executables.

Alternatively, you can distribute your stuff as a CPAN module, complete with dependencies spelled out, and let a CPAN client resolve them.  You can even use [Module::AutoInstall](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Module::AutoInstall) to perform this process outside of a CPAN client.

So you see, you're not restricted to using just core modules when shipping a Perl app.

Comment: I'll add a little more detail to the question.

Comment: Thanks, I really want to avoid installing any modules, even locally, if I can help it because it seems more trouble than its worth given the mix of platforms and lack of compiler on one of them (and I don't have much time for this work). So I really do want to use what is installed and/or pure perl.

Comment: False economy. CPAN modules are extremely portable, and you're just using Unixen! There's plenty which are pure Perl. You'll take more time reinventing the wheel, poorly, then figuring out how to install modules. You're going to want CPAN modules for your next project, learning it is an investment.

Comment: For Schwern's updated answer, there is a lot more information in perlfaq8 :)

Comment: As for saving time, re-using known, tested code is the biggest time saver.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I know about CPAN and modules. I use them. IN this case it was more trouble than it is worth, IMO, and a five-minute workaround did the job.

Comment: As `INSTALL_BASE` is not available in old versions of `ExtUtils::MakeMaker` the first thing to do is to upgrade `ExtUtils::MakeMaker` to the most recent one.

Answer (score 8):

[Module::CoreList](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Module::CoreList) has already been mentioned.  It comes with a [command-line interface](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?corelist) to make things easy.  It's great if you have it installed already, or have a program that needs to figure out what may not come with a particular version of Perl.

If you want to know what modules come with your particular version of perl, you can run `perldoc perlmodlib` on the command line for a complete list.  For older or newer versions of Perl, you can just go to [Perl's page on the CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl/) and select the version you want (eg, 5.6.2) from the drop-down, and then navigate to the `perlmodlib` page in the documentation.  (typing `perlmodlib` into your browser's text search will help).

If you're thinking of *not* using a module because it's not core on an older version of Perl, then you may wish to consider using [PAR, the Perl Archiver](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PAR), to bundle your extra dependencies, or even Perl itself!  Perl Training Australia also has a [Perl Tip on using PAR](http://perltraining.com.au/tips/2008-05-23.html) which covers the basics on getting started with PAR.

All the very best,

*Paul*

Answer (score 1):

sounds like you want [local::lib](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?local::lib).  All the benifits of cpan without root (and leaves the system perl untouched).

Answer (score 0):

A simple reference for this is in the [Appendix D](http://blob.perl.org/books/beginning-perl/3145_AppD.pdf) from the Book *[Beginning Perl](http://www.perl.org/books/beginning-perl/)*. Granted it applies to Perl 5.6 but, to my knowledge, Perl 5.8 did not remove any of these and only introduced new ones (like   Digest::MD5, File::Temp, Filter::Simple, libnet, List::Util, Memoize, MIME::Base64, Scalar::Util, Storable, Switch, Test::More, Test::Simple, Text::Balanced, Tie::File, etc.)

For each version of perl you can look in [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org). here is the [list for perl 5.8.8](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.8/index-modules-A.html)

Answer (score -1):

This question is a little less important now (I have root access on the eventual target machine so I'll just be installing the packages I need) but in case anyone is interested here's what I did:

First, run this code on each of the target systems:

```
foreach my $dir (@INC) {
    print "Directory: $dir\n";
    if (-d "$dir") {
        my @modules = `find $dir/ -name "*.pm"`;
        foreach my $m (@modules) {
            my $label = $m;
            $label =~ s|\n$||;
            $label =~ s|//+|/|g;
            $label =~ s|^$dir/||;
            print "$label\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Note you need a *nix system with a find command. Dump the output into three files, sorted. Then use commands like this (from memory):

```
grep -F -x -f list-1.txt list2.txt > list-12.txt
grep -F -x -f list-12.txt list3.txt > list-123.txt
```

Now list-123.txt should have the list of shared modules, more or less.

For what it's worth, all three systems shared a few extra modules, notably the XML::Parser modules.

Comment: That gets a list of modules shared between individual machines, but it doesn't say what comes with Perl. OS vendors add more modules. Sysadmins install more both from packages and from CPAN. You can untangle this, somewhat. Look at the "perl" and "vendor" lib directories. But its so not worth it.

Comment: Installing modules as root is not a good idea anyway. Unless you really want to share those modules for multiple users of the system. For a single user, a local install of the modules in a directory below the home directory is usually enough and safer as it doesn't risk to corrupt the files managed by the system packaging.

Answer (score -6):

look in you main symbol table, it will show you all the 'standard' packages available...

```
print %main::;
```

Comment: That does *not* show all modules distributed, only those that have been compiled in. Also it shows all kinds of other things.