# How long has a module been in Perl core?

Tags: perl, perl-module

The module I'm actually interested in is Sys::Hostname, but as a more general question, how can I tell how long a particular module has been a core module?  I'm curious about this with regards to the Perl version.

Comment: 'bout all I can think of is to troll through Perl release histories and see if/when it showed up in a particular version. The CPAN page for the module doesn't have a history, since it's a core module - its history is Perl's own history.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/571654 http://stackoverflow.com/q/2500892 http://stackoverflow.com/q/2049735 http://stackoverflow.com/q/2967895

Comment: Oh no another Joel in the Perl section here. Hmmm rock paper scissors for it? Nah I have been meaning to add my last name now that I have been authoring some Perl modules, want to get my name out.

Comment: @Joel Berger Would it shock you if my last name was Berger too?  Well, it would shock me since that's not my last name :-D

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Would [Module::CoreList](http://perldoc.perl.org/Module/CoreList.html) help?

From withing Perl:

```
print Module::CoreList->first_release('Sys::Hostname');
```

From the command line:

```
corelist -d Sys::Hostname
```

Comment: It prints `5`. Yay. I don't know if this is what the asker wants but I learned about a new interesting module.

Comment: Note that it comes with a `corelist` command-line interface that gives you a bit nicer output.

Comment: +1: Love this site. You learn something new everyday. I've always gone through perldoc.perl.org and just keep setting back the "Version" drop down to see when the module appears in that webpage. This is way better.